# Set firebase token on multipart/form-data POST request

Tags: jquery, python, angularjs, google-app-engine

I want to upload a picture to my google app engine standard env. backend that employs firebase auth. More specifically, I want to save the picture to the blobstore. 
I use angularJS (i.e. 1.x) for the frontend.
I use the cloud enpoints framework, however for the blob upload, I have a minimal WSGIApplication. 
Google [requires](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob):

> # To upload files to the blobstore, the request method must be "POST"
>    # and enctype must be set to "multipart/form-data".

My Plan is to also set the 'Authorization' Header to include the firebase token (seem viable?)

If I use a simple `<form>` element, I cannot set the header (right?)

Is there a simple way to do this using angularJS?

If it is only possible using jQuery's ajax request, could you show me how (for dummies, I have been using google's gapi client library and in combination with angularJS managed to avoid having to deal with jQuery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the uploaded files in an array called uploadedfiles, you can add the files to Form data and then assign your authorization token in the headers

```
var token = <Your token>;

var fd = new FormData();
var fileCount = 0;
angular.forEach(uploadedfiles, function (uploadedFile) {
                    fileCount += 1;
                    fd.append("file" + fileCount, uploadedFile);
                 });

$http.post(uri, fd, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {
                                'Content-Type': undefined,
                                'Authorization': JSON.stringify(token)                                                              
                            }
                    }
                )
```